# JMeter - Distributed Testing - Remote machines are unable to start the test

Tags: testing, jmeter, distributed

One master and Two slave machines. Added IP addresses to properties file's and able to connect to two slaves from Master on other applications.

For this particualr app , When i click RemoteStartAll , all i can see is the below info in logs , but nothing starts. Inside the slave machine , on the server cmd prompt , i see test started and finished at the same time  :

```
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: 10.XXX.XX.XXX 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: 10.XXX.XX.XXX 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Starting remote engines 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Starting the test @ Wed Mar 16 09:15:07 PDT 2016 (1458144907121) 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: sent test to 10.XXX.XX.XXX basedir='.' 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: Sending properties {} 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: sent run command to 10.XXX.XX.XXX 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,10.XXX.XX.XXX) 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,10.XXX.XX.XXX) 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: sent test to 10.XXX.XX.XXX basedir='.' 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: Sending properties {} 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: sent run command to 10.XXX.XX.XXX 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been started 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,10.XXX.XX.XXX) 
2016/03/16 09:15:07 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,10.XXX.XX.XXX)
```

Comment: Similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292895/how-to-perform-remote-testing-in-linux-environment