# JMeter: Distributed (Remote) Testing in Linux Environment

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, distributed-testing

I setup a distributed load testing environment using JMeter. I am using **Three Linux Machines** (RedHat)(IPs:`xxx.xxx.xxx.121`,`xxx.xxx.xxx.122`,`xxx.xxx.xxx.123`) using Secured Shell from my Windows 8.1.

I have fulfilled the prerequisite to perform Distributed test:

1. All machines(Client & Slaves) are in the same subnet.
2. Firewall is disabled for all machines.
3. JMeter(2.13) and JDk version(1.6.0_25) are same for all.

`Client(Master) Machine :xxx.xxx.xxx.123
 Server(Slave) Machines: xxx.xxx.xxx.122,xxx.xxx.xxx.121`

I did the following:

**1)** Added the following to client (master) **jmeter.properties** file:

**`remote_hosts= xxx.xxx.xxx.122,xxx.xxx.xxx.121`**

**2)** Added the following to servers (in each slave machines) **jmeter-server**:

**`RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx.123`**(Client Machine IP)

**3)** Then started **jmeter-server** from those two Slave machines(**xxx.xxx.xxx.122,xxx.xxx.xxx.121**) using this command

`./jmeter-server`

and get following **output**.Which means the slave machines are started.

**Output of xxx.xxx.xxx.121:**

```
Created remote object: UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[xxx.xxx.xxx.123:41864](local),objID:[1707296d:154c281318b:-7fff, -8101068266055605468]]]
```

**Output of xxx.xxx.xxx.122:**

```
Using local port: 4000
Created remote object: UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[xxx.xxx.xxx.123:4000](local),objID:[-2a2acf13:154c285ffa2:-7fff, 2939294752655639469]]]
```

Now I ran the following command from **client machine**(xxx.xxx.xxx.123) to start **remote tests**.

`./jmeter -n -t RemoteTest.jmx -r`

It provided me with the following output:

```
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using RemoteTest.jmx
Configuring remote engine: xxx.xxx.xxx.121
Configuring remote engine: xxx.xxx.xxx.122
Starting remote engines
Starting the test @ Wed May 18 06:27:52 GMT 2016 (1463552872376)
Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: xxx.xxx.xxx.123; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: xxx.xxx.xxx.123; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Remote engines have been started
```

**Output of jmeter.log file (xxx.xxx.xxx.123)**

```
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_GB 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading user properties from: /usr/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/user.properties 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading system properties from: /usr/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/system.properties 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2015 The Apache Software Foundation 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 2.13 r1665067 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.6.0_25 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Linux 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=amd64 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=UTF-8 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United Kingdom) 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United Kingdom) 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=/usr/apache-jmeter-2.13 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =/usr/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =/usr/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: IP: 127.0.0.1 Name: Switch018 FullName: localhost.localdomain 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='/usr/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin' 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='/usr/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin' 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file version 1656252 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 2.8 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: All converter versions present and correct 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Loading file: RemoteTest.jmx 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager: Settings: Delete null: true Check: true Allow variable: true Save: false Prefix: COOKIE_ 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Cannot find .className property for htmlParser, using default 
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is  
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is  
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is  
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is  
2016/05/18 06:52:22 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Creating summariser <summary> 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: xxx.xxx.xxx.121 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: xxx.xxx.xxx.122 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Starting remote engines 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Starting the test @ Wed May 18 06:52:23 GMT 2016 (1463554343104) 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.' 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.' 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 ERROR - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: xxx.xxx.xxx.123; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: Interrupting RMI Reaper 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 ERROR - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: xxx.xxx.xxx.123; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused 
2016/05/18 06:52:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been started
```

**So what could be the exact solution to overcome this Exception.**
I have spent the last two days exploring **StackOverflow** and **Stack Exchange** for similar kind of questions and already tried almost all of the possible solutions but still can't get rid of this exception.Actually, I failed!!!!**So please be specific and detail at your answers.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx.123` 
should be either

```
RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
```

or

`RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<ip of jmeter server>`

Also this should be set if you are getting this error

ERROR - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

1. Add RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (on slave machine)
2. Add ipaddress hostname to /etc/hosts file (on master machine)

on my system(master),/etc/hosts mentioned 127.0.0.1 hostname.
I removed 127.0.0.1 and added public Ip address

Answer (score -2):

edit the file  in the slave server,and set the value is:`enter code here`
RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.5.38
The IPaddress is you slave server.
or 
run command immediate：
./jmeter-server -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.5.38