# JMeter Master Slave configuration is not working in CentOS

Tags: centos, jmeter, master-slave

I set up a Master-Slave load testing environment using JMeter. I am using 3 CentOS machines with following IP's

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.1 (Master)
xxx.xxx.xxx.2 (Slave1)
xxx.xxx.xxx.3 (Slave2)
```

Here are the steps I did.

1) Added the following to the **slaves** jmeter.properties file:

```
remote_hosts=xxx.xxx.xxx.1
```

2) Added the following to **master** jmeter-server file

`#RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx.2`     `

Then when I'm executing the following command from the `/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin` folder of `xxx.xxx.xxx.2` Slave machine.(I don't have root user access have only SUDO root access)

```
sudo ./jmeter-server
```

I'm getting the error

```
./jmeter-server: line 32: ./jmeter: Permission denied
```

Is my Master-Slave setup is correct? Am I doing something wrong here?
Do I need to do anything else to setup master-slave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to client (master) **jmeter.properties** file:

```
remote_hosts= xxx.xxx.xxx.2,xxx.xxx.xxx.3
```

Add the following to servers (in each slave machines) **jmeter-server**:

`RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx.2` for (Slave1)

&

`RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx.3` for (Slave2)

Then start **`jmeter-server.sh`** from those two Slave

machines(`xxx.xxx.xxx.2`,`xxx.xxx.xxx.3`) using this command

```
./jmeter-server
```

Then ran the following command from the client machine(xxx.xxx.xxx.1) to start remote start all the slaves.

```
./jmeter -n -t <testscript.jmx> -r
```

See this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292895/how-to-perform-remote-testing-in-linux-environment).

Comment: When starting jmeter-server.sh from Slave machines (xxx.xxx.xxx.2,xxx.xxx.xxx.3) using command ./jmeter-server getting the error Permission denied. Then when i try with sudo ./jmeter-server getting the error ./jmeter-server: command not found. Im executing from JMETER_HOME/bin folder.

Comment: It means you don't have the execute permission for `jmeter-server.sh`.You can verify this by running `ls -l jmeter-server.sh`.This [Thread](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203371/run-script-sh-vs-bash-script-sh-permission-denied) might help.You need to grant executable permission to that file.

Comment: Master slave setup is working now. But there is an issue. It is not reading the data file from the folder. eg;/home/test/jmeter/datafiles/data1.txt is the location of the CSV data file in the JMeter script. It is not reading the data and null value is assigning in the execution. I have put the data file in the same location in master and slaves.

Comment: Where can i find the .jtl file?

Comment: ./jmeter -n -t <testscript.jmx> -r - l <outputfile.jtl>

Comment: you will find the outputfile in `apache-jmeter-2.13/bin` directory.You can give any name you want for the `.jtl` file